# Determination of Word Classes

Tags: nlp

Is there an open source library or program which can determine the word class (noun, pronoun, verb, adverb etc.) for each word  in a given English sentence?

Comment: What you're looking for is a part-of-speech tagger (POS tagger).

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling me the proper designation!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at the Stanford POS-tagger. Its in my opinion one of the easiest to get started with. Its available for download here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml

Comment: Thanks. I tested it, but the results were disappointing. In "He started to walk to and fro." both to's were tagged as TO, but the second one is actually an adverb. In "Life is but a dream.", "but" was tagged as conjunction, although in this context it's an adverb. Of course these cases are tricky, but I would have expected that a software developed by specialists in the field would do better. Are there perhaps other POS taggers which handle my examples better?